# Button not being recognized

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a button which removes an element from the DOM.

The problem now is the button doesn't appear until a new item is added to the to-do list.

I created the function to delete an item by passing its id into the function but I am not returning an error and the button is not working.

Is there something with the code? Here is the code snippet:

```
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector('.cancel__btn');

function deleteItem(id) {
    if (el) {
        el = document.querySelector(`.task["task-${id}"]`);
        cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', id => {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            console.log("clicked");
        });

        }       

};
```

Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Why 'id' needed in your listener arrow expression? Why do you add event listeners every time when call delete item function? Need all code, create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: @DimaVak here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/0fn85mh4/

Comment: @DimaVak would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues in the code.  You're using an attribute selector instead of an id selector.  Your id value needs to be kept track of inside the scope, because it is declared out of scope and thus will use the last value of id.  Incremented position is also problematic.  Your cancelBtn variable won't work, because it is selecting on page load, whereas you need to use each cancelBtn created.  Your cancelBtn event binding is incorrect.  You're supposed to bind each cancelBtn, and not inside your delete function.

```
const newTask = document.querySelector('#add__task-btn');

const box = document.querySelector('#box');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.task__container');
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector('.cancel__btn');



let id = 0;
function addTaskFunc() {

    const aTask = `
    <div class="task" id="task-${id}">
    <button class="done__btn">
        <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>
    </button>
    <p>${box.value}</p>
    <button class="priority">Make priority</button>
    <button class="cancel__btn">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    </button>

    </div>
`;

    const x = box.value;
    taskList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', aTask);
    box.value = '';
    let cid = id;
        var cancelBtn = document.querySelector(`#task-${id} .cancel__btn`);
        cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
          deleteItem(cid);
        });

id++;
}

newTask.addEventListener('click', addTaskFunc);

function deleteItem(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(`task-${id}`);
        el.remove();        


}
```

Comment: It works!! About the href attribute, it was from a code I copied from a course, I later figured that it wasn't meant to be. I am still very new to programming but why does id have to be assigned to cid?

Comment: that is a scope issue.  the id in that case is outside the closure to the function, so it is trying to use the value of id after the last increment executed (after the function has been called multiple times).  whereas when the variable cid is inside the closure, it only uses the current id value to that function

Answer (score -1):

you are not listening to button click activity

```
   <button class="cancel__btn" onClick="deleteItem()">
```